# Creating a PHP function triggered when shady DROP like queries are performed

Tags: php, security, warnings

I'm trying to code `If (the query contains any common attack terms, over 80 characters etc) { execute function  }`

I know preg_replace allows characters but is there a function to disallow set strings or how to build something like:

```
if(isset( contains['DROP, OR, 1-1, etc]) ) {  

    $message = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
    $message = $_SERVER[""];
    mail('admins@website.com', 'Shady Query Going on', $message);

}
```

I know various plugins send warnings of multiple login attempts and lockouts etc. I'm looking to do the same with SQLi attempts

UPDATE: Turns out that this is in fact a useful plugin - [Better WP Security](http://bit51.com/software/better-wp-security/) emails you when bad logins and other shady business goes on. No one answered my question either, seems like a bunch of elitist rants...
Thanks to @Rook and @Thawab tho!

Comment: What is the point? SQL Injection isn't new and we've got an arsenal of tools to help protect us.

Comment: This is what is commonly termed a "false sense of security". There are more productive things to concern yourself with than implementing things like that. Like, learning how to work with queries in a safe and valid manner. See: http://php.net/pdo for the right way to start.

Comment: Not to mention that it's highly unlikely that your blacklist would be complete...you should _absolutely_ protect against SQL injection the proper way.

Comment: What’s wrong with searching for “drop”? Asking for a web application firewall is a sure sign for me that one wants to take the easy way instead of the proper way.

Comment: It should be noted that `mysql_query()` doesn't allow query stacking.  There for the query  `select * from users;drop table users`  is invalid.  An attacker will use an attack like `select * from users into outfile '/var/www/backdoor.php' truncate line '<?php eval($_GET[e])?>'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using http://phpids.org/ in your script since it can detect more attacks.

Comment: +1 this is actually a good suggestion.  It has a number of great rules that look for sql injection.

Answer (score -1):

If you properly protect your site against SQL injection you absolutely don't need this. However, to implement it...

```
function checkForBlacklistedTerms($string)
{
    $blacklisted = array('DROP', '--', 'KILL', 'BLAH', 'BLIH');
    foreach($blacklisted as $bl) { 
        if( strpos($string, $bl) !== FALSE ) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if( checkForBlacklistedTerms($searchquery) || strlen($searchquery) > 80 )
{
   // warning code goes here
}
```

Comment: That would certainly be an appropriate term :)
Regardless, there's no harm in answering his question.

Comment: Thanks guys and I agree about the SQL. I'm using a PDO connection and am working hard on my SQL but I didn't ask about those. I still think it would be a great idea to get emailed when some jerk tries to drop my tables because he can't get a date on Saturday night :)

Comment: That first sentence is a bit like saying "Trust me it's useless but hey, what the hell, do this."

Comment: Heh...just make sure you use prepared statements with bound params

Comment: @JaredFarrish I told him he didn't need it, not that it was useless, though I suppose that is a bit of a semantic argument.

Comment: @user1440240 - You're grossly overestimating your understanding of the threat.

Comment: I just want a list of my most obvious enemies. Is that really that crazy?

Comment: @user1440240 - For instance, this [little gem](http://serverfault.com/questions/309309/what-is-muieblackcat) tapped on our gates and checked our windows on a (non-PHP) server. Your concept is not going to do anything for this type of threat, and this is more numerous and more dangerous than a "bored, poorly smelling tool in some mother's basement".

Comment: That's from a bot. Wouldn't most tools in Mom's basement be running PHP? And dangerous? 
And Kronick mentioned blocking attacker's IP's... You think using the logs instead of a warning script then?

Comment: I believe that the point he's getting at here is that security threats have many appearances and are always changing and getting more complex. There is no single solution to protect against the wide array of possible attacks, and you should be more focused on securing your site in multiple ways than techniques like this. By the time you get the e-mail warning you (if you even do) your entire database may already be destroyed (or worse).

Comment: @user1440240 - David summed it up fairly well. There are known techniques; investigate and use those. Like [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which you describe; it's *already here*. The concept you're alluding to with a person sitting in a room sending you random `DROP` fragments belies what's going on really, and you can't design a control or mitigation if you don't understand the risk and peril to begin with.

Comment: @user1440240 - And if you don't now the truly tragic and bemusedly amusing story of [*Little Bobby Tables*](http://bobby-tables.com/), have some fun and read that.

Comment: @jaredfarrish That's pretty cool! Thanks a lot guys for your input. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Haha my GF used that cartoon on the first page of her Final on SQL injection.

Comment: @user1440240 You're going to have to stop with the insulting "can't get a date" and "mom's basement" stuff. It sounds like you're trying to knock your betters down a peg, as the people you're describing clearly have a better handle on developing secure applications than you do.

Comment: @meagar What are you talking about?